# "Most important absolute property in mathematics" according to Osborne

Tags: soft-question, homological-algebra

The other day I read M. Scott Osborne's book on homological algebra. On page 33 he states the following theorem.

> $E$ is injective if and only if $E$ is an absolute direct summand, that is, $E$ is a direct summand of any module having $E$ as a submodule.

He then continues to write:

> This is probably the most important absolute property in mathematics, even compared to the notion of an absolute neighborhood retract in topology.

Unfortunately, he doesn't give any justification for this rather bold claim. So I was wondering if anyone here could do so? Or maybe debunk it as an exaggeration?

Comment: It is certainly a very important fact, because it implies any short exact sequence $0 \to E \to F \to G \to 0$ with $E$ injective is a split short exact sequence, and therefore preserved by any additive functor whatsoever. This in turn makes it possible to compute right derived functors...

Comment: I am inclined to think that such statements are (a) inherently statements of opinion, not fact, and (b) on the whole rather silly. Take it to mean simply that in some area(a) of mathematics this is a very useful property.

Comment: As you know, "God made the integers, all else is the work of man". What is an absolute important property of integers ? To be or not to be prime, perhaps.

Comment: Why is it more important than the similar property of projective modules?

Comment: ...because very man either loves projectives and despises injectives or viceversa  (flat modules lie in between). I love projectives.